# list sub-directories and do something with select and case in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, select, case

I need to list sub-directories like this: (list of sub-directories are unknown, hence can't be hard-coded in a option array)

1. 11g
2. 12c
3. 18c
4. 19c

when an option is selected (for example: 4) files inside sub-directory 19c are to be listed.

Can anyone advise how to achieve this in shell script?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit more. This is fairly unclear. Also what did you try so far?

Comment: POSIX shell solution only, or is `bash` also okay for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BASH List Possible Files and Select One](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511127/bash-list-possible-files-and-select-one)

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for something like this
(does not work with hidden directories)

```
export PS3="select directory (q to quit): "
select dir in */
  do
    test -e "$dir" && ls "$dir"
    break
done
```